# Why does gmail mess up my design here?

Tags: html, email

This is what my php script outputs (sans the actual link)

```
<div style="font-size: 14px; color: #333333; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<strong>Activitate</strong>: <a href="link">tip test2</a> <br>
<strong>Data inregistrarii</strong>: 23.11.2012 11:26:57<br>
<strong>Data scadenta</strong>: 23.11.2012<br>
<strong>Descriere</strong>: test
</div>
```

and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aku2w.png) (imgur link) is how gmail renders it. Is there any way to prevent it form doing so? It's breaking up the div and adding a purple color to the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMail adds purple color to the text it detects as a quote from the previous email in the conversation. In more extreme cases, it even adds a collapse/expand element (as noted here: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1357852&ctx=cbo&cbid=27218276&cbrank=1#reading).

> Quoted text from earlier in the conversation is now collapsed within the "Show trimmed text" icon  rather than a text link. Click it to show or hide the trimmed content. Signatures are also collapsed under an ellipsis.

Normally, you should not worry about it, nor I think you can prevent that except by not sending the same text every time.

Comment: makes sense seeing that I'm testing the functionality and sendint a bajillion emails to myself with roughly the same data.

Comment: @Bogdan and these bajillion emails are collapsed into one conversation? :-)

Comment: of course. Makes it so fun when I need to send a new one to test.

Comment: Perhaps you could look for a `x-gmail-thread-id` SMTP header or something in that sense.